# VirtualHost 443 seems to be doing nothing when confgiured

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, https

I'm running an Apache2 setup, and it seems that everything I put inside the `<VirtualHost *:443>` tag gets completely ignored in the customconf.conf which is located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/customconf.conf file. However everything inside `<VirtualHost *:80>`  works fine.

I've tried everything from a ProxyPass to trying to setup an ErrorDocument or even a Redirection, and no matter what is inserted inside the tag, nothing happens at all.

Here is my `customconf.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    RedirectPermanent / https://google.com/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem

    # Rest of your site config
    # ...
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: It does appear that when typing something completely incorrect, like just a random sequence of characters, restarting Apache will cause an error. But apart from that nothing else enclosed inside the VirtualHost tag appears to do anything.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's my understanding that if the VirtualHost was working properly then the site redirection would have been invoked when on port 443, the same way the redirection to https occurs on the VirtualHost *80 tag.

Comment: OK, so what actually does happen?

Comment: The issue is that nothing actually does happen. My end goal here is to setup a ProxyPassReverse so that I can serve an Express application running on port 3000 on Apache on port 443. But considering that I've tried everything I can think of to try and get the ProxyPassReverse working, I'm left thinking that maybe the VirtualHost tag itself isn't functioning properly.

Comment: Nothing only would happen if you didn't actually try to load the web page. Something happened. What was it?

Comment: It would just load the index.html at /var/www/html I just tried setting up the ProxyPassReverse using HTTP (and VirtualHost *80) and it worked fine, but switching to HTTPS (using VirtualHost *443) still won't work as the same index.html file is being served instead of the Node application.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I still haven't proven if `<VirtualHost *:443>`  is actually working properly or not, I did still manage to solve the problem I was having by inserting my configuration for `<VirtualHost *:443>`  outside of the tag. Maybe not a solution to my original question, but that's irrelevant now considering my ProxyPassReverse now works properly.